# load a view with jquery in MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I work with `MVC 3`. In a view I have 2 radio buttons. When I click on one of the two radiobuttons then I try with jquery to load a view. But it doesn's work.

I am completley new to `MVC` and `jQuery`.

Here is my code:

```
  $('radioButtonFor#dutch').click(function () {
      load('/MyController/MyView', parameterForTheView)
  });
```

And here is one of the radio buttons:

```
             @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsBelg, false, new { id = "dutch" })
```

Please help me!

Ronald

Comment: Could you post the code of your MyView controller action, and also the details of any firebug console errors you are getting

Answer (score 3):

Your jquery reference to the Radio Button should read as follows:

```
  $("#dutch").click(function () {
      load('/MyController/MyView', parameterForTheView)   
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

is load method your own method?
jquery should look like

```
$("#container").load(...);
```